# Android: Spaces not going to new line at the end of EditText line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multiline EditText.

Whenever the input text is reaching its maximum width, the line breaks and the text is moving to the next line.

However, it isn't working well with spaces. When there is an input like "blabla" and then lots of spaces, the line not breaks and the text is being pushed to the left until it "goes out" of the EditText.

How can I treat the spaces as "regular" characters for it to work?

thanks!

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Comment: show your xml please

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the horizonal scrolling on trailing spaces, I think you will have to give up `android:gravity="center"`.  That is causing the scrolling.  I tried adding `android:scrollHorizontally="false"`, but it had no effect.  I couldn't find a way to stop the scrolling when center gravity is specified.